# Cannot solve 'Undefined Index' error with ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I know this question has been asked many times, but I went through almost all the proposed solutions, and none of them seem to work. To begin with, this is my file structure:

```
index.php
-js
  map.js
-css
  main.css
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I'm using Google Maps API, I placed many markers in different locations on the map. When the user clicks one of the markers, I want a specific variable to be submitted to index.php so I can use it in an SQL query. This is my code:

### map.js

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

     return function() {
        var place = 1234;
        // $.post('/index.php',{'place' : place},function(data,status){alert(status)});

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: '/index.php',
            data: "place="+place,
            success: function(data,status){
                alert(status)
            }
        });

     }
})(marker, i));
```

### index.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["place"])) {
       echo ($_POST["place"]);
    }
?>
```

I referenced those jQuery libraries in my :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

I tried all possible syntax changes, and it has been bugging me for days now.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: How about the simpler `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  var  place = 1234;
  $.post('/index.php',{'place' : place},function(data){alert(data)})
})`

Comment: @JayBlanchard It POST http://localhost/index.php; then  GET http://localhost/xampp/

Comment: @mplungjan tried that, did not work

Answer (score 0):

The index file is in an upper directory, you have to change

```
url: '/index.php',
```

to

```
url: '../index.php',
```

Comment: Still no hope, it returns a success, so I assume it successfully posts to the url, but it's not setting the variable 'place' in the php code.

Comment: try without return just google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

     //return function() {
        var place = 1234;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: '/index.php',
            data: "place="+place,
            success: function(data,status){
                alert(status)
            }
        });

     //}
})(marker, i));